# How do I override the REST serializer in Yii2?

Tags: php, api, rest, yii2

I'm building a REST API with Yii2.  Normally the request response looks something like this:

```
    {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=1"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=2"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=50"
        }
    },
    "_meta": {
        "totalCount": 1000,
        "pageCount": 50,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "perPage": 20
    }
}
```

I want to override the serializer so that the fields contained in the "_meta" array are instead included in the root of the array, i.e. the same level as "items" and "_links".  How and where do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html#data-serializing) you create a new Serializer class. So, basically, you extend `yii\rest\Serializer` and rewrite the `serialize()` method. Then you set your custom serializer for your controller.

```
class MySerializer extends Serializer 
{
    public function serialize($data) 
    {
        $d = parent::serialize($data);
        $m = $d['_meta'];
        unset($d['_meta']);
        return array_merge($d, $m);
    }
}

class MyController extends ActiveController
{
    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\MySerializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked perfectly.  And just to complete the answer, I placed the new MySerializer class in the application/components folder and then in the MyController class used: 

'class' => 'app\components\MySerializer',